# Extended CreateView does not give the desired output in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I have two tables in my **model.py**:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'partner'

class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    partner = models.ForeignKey('Partner', null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'device'
```

I create a View for generic form generation:

```
class CreateDeviceView(CreateView):
    model = Device
    template_name = 'device_form.html'
    #form_class = DeviceForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('partners')
```

Which I am calling from the **urls.py** :

```
 url(r'^device/new', CreateDeviceView.as_view(), name='device-new'),
```

The template **device_form.html** is:

```
<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save"/>
    </form>
```

The generated create form has got values in the selection menu (for the foreign keys): Partner Object,Partner Object...
How can I get the values in select menu to be Partner.name?
I tried to build my own form but I did't get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Partner` model, add a `__unicode__` method:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'partner'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution.